# Sumifs #VALUE! error when using dynamic ranges with filter function based on another dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am getting a #VALUE! error in a sumifs function when I use dynamic ranges that use the Filter function based on another dynamic range. The ranges are defined below. I am able to get the sumifs to work if I reference the dynamic ranges in separate cells and then reference those in a SUMIFS function.

Sumifs formula (error):

```
=SUMIFS(BilledAmount,BilledInvNum,UNIQUE(ARInvoice2,0,0))
```

Sumifs formula (no error): `=SUMIFS(AD2#,AE2#,AF2#)` where BilledAmount is referenced in AD2, BilledInvNum is referenced in AE2, and UNIQUE(ARInvoice2,0,0) is referenced in AF2.

Dynamic Ranges:

BilledArray

```
= OFFSET(Billed!$D$8,0,-3,COUNTA(Billed!$D:$D)-1,30)
```

BilledAmount

```
= FILTER(BilledArray,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0})
```

BilledInvNum

```
= FILTER(BilledArray,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1})
```

ARInvoice2

```
= OFFSET('17015 Drop'!$M$1,1,0,COUNTA('17015 Drop'!$M:$M)-1,1)
```

There are no blanks in the BilledAmount and BilledInvNum ranges and the data in BilledAmount is all numbers. I have used the Columns function to verify that both ranges are pulling in 1 column. I have used the Rows function to verify that both ranges are pulling in the same number of rows. I have a similar sumifs function in the file that works with dynamic ranges, however these ranges do not use the Filter function.

Why would I get the error in the first sumifs above but not the second? It's essentially the same data.

Comment: Why not use `=INDEX(BilledArray,,24)` instead of FILTER (Same for BilledInvNum) and for the BilledArray you could also use a INDEX/ SEQUENCE version rather than a volatile OFFSET version

Comment: SUMIFS only works with ranges, and when you use `AD2#` it passes the spilled range and not the array to the formula.

Comment: I didn't go through what you are actually trying to do but `OFFSET()` is volatile anyways. I'd rather go with `BYROW()` or any other `LAMBDA()` function to go through multiple rows if that is what you are trying. Since you are on ms365 that would not be a problem with these function now in the production channel.

Comment: @P.b Changing the BilledArray to the INDEX version got the SUMIFS working. I never knew about the different way to build a dynamic range. Thank you.

Comment: `=INDEX($1:$1048576,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)-1,,8),SEQUENCE(1,30))` maybe this is useful as a non-volatile version of BilledArray